# wordpress function is not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this button

```
   <button class="button1" id="myid1">Activate</button>
```

when user click this button then this jquery executes and we are getting alert also.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(\'#myid1\').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $el = $(this).parents().eq(1);
        remove_element($el);
        var data1 = {
        action: \'enable_function1\',
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data1, function(response) {
           alert(\'Congratulations,Activated' \');
        });               });
 });
```

here is my WordPress function

```
function enable_function1() {
    add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'someotherfunction');
    }
```

but nothing is being written by mod_rewrite_rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your wordpress backend you need to do this. The **action** is not the name of the function, it's used by wordpress to identify which function to execute

```
function your_function() {
    add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'someotherfunction');
    }

add_action("wp_ajax_enable_function1", "your_function");

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_enable_function1", "your_function");
```

check this for more details : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: what is this for .wp_ajax_nopriv_enable_function1

Comment: it's used  (for users who are not logged in) Read the Notes in the link i sent and the end

Comment: you need to check what's inside you function **add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'someotherfunction');** try to replace it with a simpe code and you will see that the logic works, But am not sure if it's a good place to apply a filter there.

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting the `mod_rewrite_rules` filter to do here. This filter is to modify the rewrite rules for output to .htaccess. Calling the filter on an AJAX call probably won't accomplish much at all since .htaccess isn't getting written to in this case. Please see: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1563

Comment: @TemaniAfif minor help. when i use if($_POST['action'] == 'name1') {

Comment: you don't need to check the action as you are sure the function will execute only for this action. We add a fucntion to each action.